# Is there a simple formula for calculating $\sum_r\binom{n}{r}$, where $1 \leq r \leq n$?

Tags: summation, combinations

I am aware that the formula for combinations is:

$$\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{(n - r)!  \:r!}$$

This gives me the numbers I want for combinations of a certain length.

However, in my case, I need the sum of these where *r* can be all the values between 1 and n.

Is there a simple formula for this (that is, something that can be put in a spreadsheet)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), we have
$$
\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}a^rb^{n-r}=(a+b)^n
$$ Putting $a=b=1$ gives

> $$
> \sum_{r=1}^n\binom{n}{r}=2^n-1.
> $$

Answer (score 2):

$n\choose r$ is the number of ways to choose $r$ objects out of $n$.

Thus, $\sum_{r=1}^n {n\choose r}$ which you are looking for is the number of ways to choose $1,2,\dots n$ items out of $n$.

For each object, we have two choices, either choose it or not choose it. Thus there are $2^n$ choices. However we have to subtract one since we can't choose 0 objects out of $n$.

Overall, the answer you want is $2^n-1$. This is a combinatorial approach.

Comment: Did you mean to write $\sum_{r = 1}^n \binom{n}{r}$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig oh yes